# Query data from date range from sqlitealchemy on sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to perform a flask-sqlalchemy query to return data based in a filter on a date field.

My model is

```
   class Transaction(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'transactions'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    transaction_date = db.Column(db.Date)

    def __init__(self, id, transaction_date):
        self.id = id
        self.transaction_date = transaction_date
```

On the sqlite database the date is stored like '2016-12-28'.

So I'm trying to query all data where the transaction_date is greater than '2016-12-01' for example.

But when I try

```
transactions = Transaction.query.filter_by(transaction_date >= datetime.strp time('%Y-%m-%d','2016-12-01')).all()
```

I got the following error

```
NameError: name 'transaction_date' is not defined
```

If I exclude the filter_by clause the query runs perfectly, so I'm afreid I'm not querying the date in the right way.

As a amateur programmer developing for personal use I don't know very much about programming but I like to study and develop in python.

A searched for this king of error in stackoverflow and I coultn't get nothing to work, so I ask for your help guys.

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you take transaction_date from?

Comment: Have you tried `...filter(Transaction.transaction_date ....)`?

Comment: Oh thanks.. I tried with 'filter' and it worked but why ? When I just use 'filter_by' it doesn't recognize my model field.